# How to batch append a directory, while skipping over files already appended

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I got this code in a batch file for a Windows 7 client:

```
forfiles /C "cmd /c IF (@file==(S)*)(echo @file) Else (REN @file (S)@file)"
```

However, now it does nothing. I know the `@file (S)@file works. I can't figure out the IF statement to skip over files already appended. Anyone know why? Any CMD guys out there?

I'd like (the original dir):

```
Text1.txt
Fileblah.txt
dat.dat
(S)alreadyappendedfile.jpg
```

To become(desired dir):

```
(S)Text1.txt
(S)Fileblah.txt
(S)dat.dat
(S)alreadyappendedfile.jpg
```

I can run the code without the IF statement but I'd get THIS (which I want to avoid):

```
(S)Text1.txt
(S)Fileblah.txt
(S)dat.dat
(S)(S)alreadyappendedfile.jpg
```

After I added the IF statement though, now the code does NOTHING at all.

Comment: What happens when you run this? What do you expect to happen vs what is actually happening?

Comment: @MattWilliamson Nothing happens, I EXPECT any file with (S) already in it to just echo the name, I expect every other file to APPEND an (S) to it. I added an example for clarity.

Comment: The problems is in this line `@file==(S)*` Forfiles doesn't take wildcards like that. You can just use the /M option but that doesn't help much in your scenario. Also, I think the parenthesis around the s are throwing it off too. I'll have to test that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will provide you with a temporary batch file to rename the files.
Examine `renfiles.bat.txt` in notepad and rename/launch it if you are happy with it.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
dir /b /a-d |repl "^[^(].*" "ren \q$&\q \q(S)$&\q" xa >renfiles.bat.txt
```

This should do the same for a recursive list of files.

```
dir /b /s /a-d |find /i /v "\(S)" |repl ".*\\(.*)" "ren \q$&\q \q(S)$1\q" xa >renfiles.bat.txt
```

Comment: this works, but the complexity isn't specifically what I needed, since I have to explain it to someone else. HOWEVER, it can be applied recursively, though I haven't tested it yet, since I don't understand it all quite yet. I got some reading to to. It is the right answer for anyone looking to do what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not dead set on using forfiles, here is a way to do it with a batch script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d %~dp0test1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
  set file=%%a
  if /i "!file:~0,3!" EQU "(s)" (
  echo %%~nxa : yes ) else ren "%%~nxa" "(s)%%~nxa"
)
```

Change paths as necessary

Comment: I like this one, it's the best one so far that is simple and not too hard to understand. I'm not sure how this would scale to something similar but applied recursively. I'm gonna try though. Thanks for helping.

Comment: To make it recursive is simple. Add `/s` to the dir command in the for loop on line 5.

Comment: `ren "%%~nxa"` should be `ren "%%a"` for recursive renaming and the `set file=%%a` should be `set file=%%~nxa`

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
    'dir /a-d /b * ^|findstr /i /b /v /c:"(s)"'
) do ren "%%~a" "(S)%%~nxa"
```

Anyway, this will fail if any of the new files have the same name as one of the old ones (before renaming). The final name will be the same of a still existing file and the rename operation will fail.

You need to define a behavior for such case.

Comment: I tried this and it had hiccups with files named similarly. IE `test.txt` & `test - copy (1).txt` where only the original would get appended.

Comment: @EricAnthony, sorry, it's the third time today i forget something. Maybe it is time to rest. This time i forget the "delims" clause in the for command. Answer updated.